# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:androidApis

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm trying to run "flutter build appbundle" in terminal. I already search for some solution but none of it has the same error as I get.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:parseReleaseLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\verena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\verena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

This is the code from my "android\build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is my "android\app\build.gradle"

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.demo.desketsa"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<1.4.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.2'
}
```